# React useEffect cleanup with current props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I ran into a need of cleaning a useEffect when component is unmounted but with an access to the current props. Like componentWillUnmount can do by getting this.props.whatever

Here is a small example:
Click "set count" button 5 times and look at your console. You'll see 0 from the console.log in component B, regardless "count" will be 5
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vibrant-feather-v9f6o

How to implement the behavior of getting current props in useEffect cleanup function (5 in my case)?

**UPDATE:**
Passing count to the dependencies of useEffect won't help because:

1. Cleanup will be invoked on every new count is passed to the props
2. The last value will be 4 instead of the desired 5

Comment: I actually can't think of a way to do this.

Comment: You can use useRef to store the current value

Comment: @JonasWilms You can use an effect to see if a [component is unmounted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60788677/1641941) but you can never have it log 5 because component B is never rendered with a count value of 5.

Answer (score 2):

Was referenced to this question from another one so will do a bit of grave digging for it since there is no accepted answer.

The behaviour you want can never happen because B never renders with a count value of 5, component A will not render component B when count is 5 because it'll render unmounted **instead** of B, the last value B is rendered with will be 4.

If you want B to log the last value it had for count when it unmounts you can do the following:

Note that effects executes **after** all components have rendered

```js
const useIsMounted = () => {
  const isMounted = React.useRef(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return () => (isMounted.current = false);
  }, []);
  return isMounted;
};
const B = ({ count }) => {
  const mounted = useIsMounted();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    return () => !mounted.current && console.log(count);
  }, [count, mounted]);

  return <div>{count}</div>;
};
const A = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const handleClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }, []);

  if (count === 5) {
    //B will never be rendered with 5
    return <div>Unmounted</div>;
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <B count={count} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Set count</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<A />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I finally got this to work! Thanks for this. It's awful that this needs to be this complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you passed empty array as dependency list for `useEffect`, your effect function only gets registered the first time. At that time, the value of count was 0. And that is the value of count which gets attached to the function inside useEffect. If you want to get hold of the latest count value, you need your useEffect to run on every render. Remove the empty array dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => console.log(count);
})
```

or use count as the dependency. That way, your effect function is created anew every time count changes and a new cleanup function is also created which has access to the latest count value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => console.log(count);
}, [count])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to track `count` in `useEffect`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const B = ({ count }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => console.log(count);
  }, [count]);

  return <div>{count}</div>;
};

export default B;
```

Comment: In this case: 1. Cleanup will be invoked on every new count. 2. The last value will be 4 instead of the desired 5. So it won't help unfortunately